# React js route is not showing the component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When I call the Component outside the route is works perfectly fine, but inside the route it doesn't work.

the App.js file is:

```
import './App.css';
import Login from './Components/Login/Login';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Protected from './Components/Common/Protected';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Redirect exact from="/" to="/Login" >
            <Route exact path="/Login" > <Login /> </Route>
          </Redirect>
        </Switch>
      </Router>

    </div>
  );
}
```

export default App;

and these are my packages:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "ag-grid-community": "^26.0.0",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^26.0.1",
    "ag-grid-react": "^26.0.0",
    "material-table": "^1.69.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.1"
  },
```

Comment: This is not at all how `<Redirect>` works. You're not supposed to put anything inside it; you're supposed to conditionally render it based on state (initially not), then change the state so it renders when you want to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect needs to come last inside Switch. This is what you need in order for Login to be rendered:

```
return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/login">
        <Login />
      </Route>
      <Redirect to="/login" />
    </Switch>
  );
```

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work. Same issues and same errors

Comment: Then it has nothing to do with what's inside the Switch.
Here, this codesendbox was made specially for you, check it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/rr-so-hw31y. If you'll change what's inside <Switch></Switch> to your question code, you'll see that it doesn’t render Login anymore.