# TypeError: history is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, browser-history

When I am using the history.push function, it always returns this error

TypeError: history is undefined

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';


function App() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function testing() {
    history.push("/whatever");
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={testing}>Test</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My packages:

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
```

and finally, the error I'm getting:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1a4b.png)

Comment: Is it whole application code?

Comment: This is not reproducible with this portion of the code. Can you provide a codesandbox?

Comment: I think this is the only code he has. Where are your ruotes? You copied [this](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks) but you should start from [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

Comment: this is the whole code. I created a new npx react project, deleted the defaults in app.js, installed react router dom and added the code above. nothing else

Comment: There's no router, no routes, nothing. The `useHistory` hook needs a router context.

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito of course I downloaded the npm package, otherwise the project wouldn't run

Comment: Do as Giovanni says and start with the tutorial, not a random part of the API docs.

Comment: @nour never said that you need to install npm package. You need to understand how `react-router-dom` works!

Comment: @ChrisG it needs routes in order to render a certain component, the problem is it's not working at all. It is suppose to let you do the the /whatever route that shows a black page, it is showing an error instead

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito then please refer to my https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69035753/react-js-route-is-not-showing-the-component question and see that nothing with react-router-dom is working for me. Not routes, not locations and not history

Comment: Why are you making these claims despite disproving them with your own code? In the face of people correcting your assumptions? I'll never understand this. Here's a minimal example that works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-panini-cogdo?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I also posted a comment below your other question, which completely misuses <Redirect>. You need to go back to the tutorial/docs and actually look at the example code.

Comment: I found this. https://flaviocopes.com/react-router-uselocation-usehistory-undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **I assume `App` is the first component after your index.js, then you will need to wrap it around a `<BrowserRouter>` to use `useHistory()`**

Something like this in your root (index) component:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  rootElement
);
```

Comment: If anybody else finds this: while this works, <BrowserRouter> usually goes inside <App>. Check the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) for proper usage.

Comment: I wrote, `Something like this` and your `usually` doesn't mean it has to be like that. Why do you have to be too hard on yourself mate? We are all here to help!

Comment: Everybody has to start somewhere, stop yelling at people who don't know something instead of giving actual help. In the question, he just trying to test the functionality of `useHistory`. We are here to help him somehow. You must have picked the wrong place to express your anger, mate.